# Passing Date in AngularJS $http get to ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

When passing js Date objects to my ASP.NET Web Api controller, I always get null. I have tried passing strings, array of string, timespan - all those works, except Date. When inspecting the request, the date is passed like this:

```
date:"2014-03-13T15:00:00.000Z"
```

In angular:

```
$http({ 
    method: 'get', 
    url: 'api/stuff', 
    params: {
       date: new Date()
    }
);
```

In my ApiController:

```
public IEnumerable<StuffResponse> Get(
    [FromUri] DateTime? date
){ ... }
```

What is the correct way to pass dates?

Answer (score 13):

This works for me:

```
$http({ 
    method: 'get', 
    url: 'api/stuff', 
    params: {
       date: $filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The formatting of the date in your Javascript is not compatible with .NET DateTime parsing. See here for valid formats.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: either use a different format like @Rondles is saying or just take it in as a string and parse it using `DateTime.Parse`

Comment: when sending the js date through postdata, .NET manages to create a DateTime - so I guessed it would work when using get and params also..

Comment: The format of the date ("2014-03-13T15:00:00.000Z") is exactly the same for $http post data and get params, but the ApiController doesn't manage to recognize the string as a DateTime for get params.

Comment: I would suggest that you try SnareHangers approach and before you send it, convert it into a .NET recognised format. If it still doesn't work then you have a different problem. If it does work then the current formatting combined with this type of AJAX request is causing the issue.